# What is the tense called: "I have got a book"

Tags: tense

What's the name of the tense of the above-mentioned example:present simple or present perfect, or perhaps something else in modern grammar? Or simply "present"? Thanks in advance.

> I have got a book.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible analyses of this sentence.

The first is to consider "have" to be an auxiliary verb and "got" to be the past participle of "get", forming the present perfect. This tense is used to describe present states resulting from past actions. This would mean that the book was received in the past and I am in the state resulting from receiving it.

Some criticise this analysis, noting that participle form "having got a book" differs in meaning from "I have got a book". The latter doesn't really describe a past event, but simple possession.  The alternative is to treat "have got" as an idiom, meaning simple possession and essentially identical in meaning to "I have a book". As an idiom, its meaning is restricted and "having got a book" is not part of the idiomatic usage.

This is further complicated by dialectic differences. In US English, the present perfect would be formed as "I've gotten a book" and the idiom meaning possession would be "I've got a book". The former is talking about a past event, the latter is describing possession.  In UK English "gotten" is not used so there is no structural difference between the idiom and present perfect.

Some speakers will criticise the use of "I've got" to mean "I have" for redundancy, and in careful writing you can avoid "I've got" in most situations, either replacing it with "I have" or "I've received".

Comment: @ JamesK  you have answered very comprenhensively

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the most frequently made mistakes made by English speaking people.  In this case, have and got mean the same thing; therefore have got is redundant.  The correct sentence would be: I have a book.

Answer (score 0):

"I have got" is a **present perfect constuction** in the **present** tense. In this context it is equivalent to simply "I have".

Indeed:

> I have got a book

can be rendered equally as

> I have a book

Comment: It is the present perfect, but note that the perfect is a past tense.

Comment: @BillJ Normally yes, but in this case no. "I have got" is equivalent to "I have", here. There is a usage of "have got" which is indeed past tense, however, for example: "Have you got my book yet?"

Comment: You said that "I have got" is present perfect. But it's not that at all -- it's the idiomatic use of "have got", where it indicates possession In other words, this is not the perfect "have". Sorry, I should have made that clear in my first comment.

Comment: @BillJ, If you don't take it as the perfect 'have', what would you take it? If you take it as a normal verb meaning possession, then it shouldn't be followed by 'got' grammatically, IMO.

Comment: @dan That it's not the perfect "have" is evident from the fact it has no gerund-participle: "She almost regrets having got that book" has only the non-idiomatic meaning "having obtained".

Comment: @dan This may also help: [link](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv323.shtml)

Comment: Not my downvote @AngelPray

Answer (score -1):

What is the tense called, “I have got a book”

Please note the comma instead of a colon as it is all one question.
'Got' with 'have' is past participle, so you could say, "I have got a book" to refer to a book that came into your possession in the past.
"I have a book" is a reference to possession of the book in the present tense.

Answer (score -2):

The construction **I have got a book** is idiomatic but ungrammatical. It's perfectly acceptable to say, but it's really a variation of **I have a book**. Therefore it's actually *present* tense.

I you wanted to denote something in the *present perfect* tense, you'd say **I have gotten a book**, or **I've gotten a book**. If you wanted to denote something in the *simple past*, you'd say **I got a book**.

Comment: Dictionaries say the past participle of **get** can be either **got** or **gotten**. I don't understand why we can't take "*I have got a book*" as a present perfect sentence, which I think that is the same as "*I have gotten a book*".

Comment: But talking about possession,  not reception,  past simple should be "had", I believe.

Comment: @V.V. that's a different aspect of the past tense. "I had gotten" and "I have gotten" mean different things.

Comment: @dan I don't know what dictionary you're using, but they mean different things. **got** and **gotten** have different aspect.

Comment: I think there is a transatlantic misunderstanding here. *I have got a book* is fine in British English; in American English, you'd use *I have a book* for possession and *I have gotten a book* for acquisition. Even in AmE, however, it's quite unexceptional to say *I've got a book* in casual conversation.